# iOS Swift m3u8 background play doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, background, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to background play .m3u8 after pushing HOME button and coming back from foreground.

It stop when pushing back button.
Please any help.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.


    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.



    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.


    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.


    }


}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myMoviePlayerView : MPMoviePlayerViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
        myButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.height/2)
        myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        myButton.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        myButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: "onClickMyButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)

    }



    func onClickMyButton(sender: UIButton) {


        let url = NSURL(string :"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")

        myMoviePlayerView = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)

        myMoviePlayerView.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = .Streaming

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayBackDidFinish:",
            name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
            object: myMoviePlayerView.moviePlayer)

        self.presentViewController(myMoviePlayerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("moviePlayBackDidFinish:")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>**********************************</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` for playing audio that's why the problem is raised.

add a key named **Required background modes** in property list (.plist) file ..

as following picture..

[image]

And add this line in `AppDelegate` with `audioSession`

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

may you get more help from [this](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/AppDelegate.swift)

Comment: @user818992 I think you are using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` for playing audio that's why the problem is raised.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well on AVPlayer when I push power button. but 
It doesn't work when I push home button...

Comment: did you figure out how to play it on background when pushing the home button? Thanks